# Argument 1 cannot convert form string to system.type

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a repository function in .net mvc but I am getting an error "Argument 1 cannot convert form string to system.type"

```
public IQueryable <sp_GetAllRecordStages_Result> ExecuteSpStageView(DbContext dbcontext, string orderno)
{

    IQueryable<sp_GetAllRecordStages_Result> lst = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery("sp_GetAllRecordStages",orderno);
    return lst;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting - nothing is readable

Comment: Hi, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

SqlQuery really requires a type. Try:

```
IQueryable<sp_GetAllRecordStages_Result> lst = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<sp_GetAllRecordStages_Result>("sp_GetAllRecordStages",orderno);
```

Without the sp_GetAllRecordStages_Result, it expects an extra parameter with that type.